# Talend error to connect to PostgreSQL Database

Tags: postgresql, talend

I have created a job which is writing data into a table in PostgreSQL DB, this is the staging job. After the staging job is completed, another job writes the staging data into the final table which is in the same database. However, the staging job works fine but the final job fails with the below error. I have worked with Talend and Database team and everything works fine at the server level. Not sure why the final job is failing when there is no issue with the staging job. Could anyone please help with this issue.

Talend version : 7.3
PostgreSQL version : 14.2

```js
[INFO ]: aws_dev_engagebh.job_stg_view_to_ods_orders_view_0_3.Job_STG_VIEW_TO_ODS_ORDERS_VIEW - TalendJob: 'Job_STG_VIEW_TO_ODS_ORDERS_VIEW' - Start.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 10633
[statistics] connected
[FATAL]: aws_dev_engagebh.job_stg_view_to_ods_orders_view_0_3.Job_STG_VIEW_TO_ODS_ORDERS_VIEW - tDBOutput_2 SSL error: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:43)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:446)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:140)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:197)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:217)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at aws_dev_engagebh.job_stg_view_to_ods_orders_view_0_3.Job_STG_VIEW_TO_ODS_ORDERS_VIEW.tDBInput_1Process(Job_STG_VIEW_TO_ODS_ORDERS_VIEW.java:5543)
    at aws_dev_engagebh.job_stg_view_to_ods_orders_view_0_3.Job_STG_VIEW_TO_ODS_ORDERS_VIEW.runJobInTOS(Job_STG_VIEW_TO_ODS_ORDERS_VIEW.java:7971)
    at aws_dev_engagebh.job_stg_view_to_ods_orders_view_0_3.Job_STG_VIEW_TO_ODS_ORDERS_VIEW.main(Job_STG_VIEW_TO_ODS_ORDERS_VIEW.java:7316)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:370)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:313)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1290)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:401)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:373)
    at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:41)
```

Comment: Hi, could you had a bit more information of your issue and your job (a screenshot, the type of component you use, ...). I encountered a similar issue, it came from the data i was sending (quantity of it) and had to do a select with limit and offset to insert into the the new table (and also add more memery allocated to the job).